# Run netbeans java project in browser

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

How is it possible, to run netbeans project in the browser?

My project have only one frame, and uses swing. I have no idea, how is it possible, to write an embedded java application, for browsers.

Comment: You may want to use java applet, java web start ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looking into `JApplets`, this sounds to be what you are looking for.

Links:

- [Example](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap36/ch36_2.html)
- [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Java WebStart , take a look to this tutorial in [Enabling Java Web Start in Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javase-jws.html).
More information [Lesson: Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/)
Also you may interested in Applets, [Lesson: Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Comment: *"..you may (be) interested in Applets.."*  But definitely make the JWS based launch for the existing frame before you consider converting it to an applet.  The latter will not only be more work, but higher maintenance in the future.  Applets are a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to launch it in Browser then it is better in Netbeans you chose Java EE project. This you can run in browser and you can create much better GUI than swing by using HTML and CSS. Of course it will be applet based.

[Check this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html)